r-dropping in rhotic dialects
I've noticed that there's no shortage of videos where people speaking rhotic dialects drop the first r in the word "particular" (most speakers retain it, but a sizable minority doesn't). Is there a name for that phenomenon? (r-dropping?). Is there a systematic review of it (when does it happen)?

Merriam-Webster gives an alternative pronunciation without the first r.

Does this answer your question? 'Forward' pronounced more often as 'foward'? Hempl 1893 mentions "pa(r)ticular" on page 280, and Hall 2007 lists it on page 5 and discusses the general trends in this type of dissimilation

@herisson yes, thank you!
